# How to exclude the records which is got from Regular expression condition in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

In one of my query I want to exclude the records which is got from Regular Expression condition in **WHERE** clause. It means if in a table having **500** records and when i use Regular Expression in **WHERE** then i got **100** records, so that i want only rest of the records means rest **400** records. The query is like this.

```
Eg:- select ........   where regexp_like(col, '[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]')
```

whatever we are getting records from the above query I do not want. How to exclude the records which is getting from Regular expression in **WHERE** clause  so that i can filter my condition & query .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `not`?

```
where not regexp_like(col, '[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]')
```

You might need to take `NULL`s into account as well:

```
where not regexp_like(col, '[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]') or col is null
```

Comment: when i execute these then after the records could not be updated.